# Macro con excel para contar celdas con una fecha concreta

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Recibo los datos de unos contadores de electricidad cada 15 minutos y ando haciendo pruebas con macros para reducir esa ingente cantidad de datos.

El caso es que para el programa que quiero hacer quiero contar el numero de celdas que se corresponden con una misma fecha para después coger el primer y último valor del día. Para ello estoy ejecutando el siguiente código como prueba pero me da error:

```
Sub contarceldas()

Dim cuenta As Integer

cuenta = 0

Date = DateValue("June 1, 2019")

For i = 3 To 10

If Int(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Int(Date) Then cuenta = cuenta + 1

Next i

Range("B2").Value = cuenta

End Sub
```

No se si el fallo esta al ejecutar la variable date o donde puedo estar fallando en otro apartado, otra cosa que me gustaría saber para seguir avanzando es si se pueden empezar a comparar las celdas en un mes en concreto sin tener en cuenta los años o que empiece a comparar con la fecha del primer valor

El formato de las fechas que recibo del software con el que trabajo es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*EDIT*

Edito con algunas recomendaciones que me habéis hecho.

El error que recibo al ejecutar el codigo anterior es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con respecto a un ejemplo de lo que me gustaría conseguir, el excel que me exporta los datos de los contadores tiene el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Queda como la captura anterior con datos hasta las 23:45 con un periodo de 15 minutos(salvo en ocasiones que se pierden, por ello el numero de datos no es siempre el mismo).

Entonces el objetivo de mi macro es extraer en una nueva hoja el primer y ultimo valor de cada día a lo largo de un mes para ver los consumos y que me quedaran los datos tras ejecutar la macro como algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A priori creo que no es algo muy dificil de conseguir pero dada mi inexperiencia a la hora de trabajar con macros me estoy encontrando con algunos problemas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aclara en la pregunta el error que recibis. usa el boton [edit] y agregalo. Como texto!

Comment: Creo que ayudaría si pudieras poner un ejemplo del resultado que te gustaría obtener. Además, las fechas ¿están en formato texto o en formato fecha?

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación @ElierSánchezE-Infantes, soy un novato en esto y todavía no caigo en algunos detalles. Ya he editado con lo que me gustaría obtener y respondiendo a tu pregunta, me sale en un formato personalizado con tipo: [$-10C0A]dd/mm/aaaa h:mm:ss

Por lo que entiendo que si tiene formato de fecha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno pues quizá es algo complejo pero está todo explicado. No he hecho lo de contar las celdas del día y demás, simplemente he hecho que te vuelque lo que necesitas.

Si tienes alguna pregunta no dudes en consultar:

```
Option Explicit
Sub MaxMin()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Origen As Variant, Intermedio As Variant
    Dim Fecha As Date, Hora As Date
    'Para este ejercicio vamos a imaginar que el campo Fecha está en la columna A y el dato de consumo en la B
    'Deberás utilizar esa lógica y cambiar las referencias para que vayan con tus columnas correctas

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MiHoja") 'Cambia MiHoja por el nombre de la hoja
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'última fila con datos en la columna A
        Origen = .Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Value 'guardamos los datos de fecha y consumo en una matriz
    End With

    'dimensionamos un array con tantas filas como el original pero con 3 columnas. Fecha, hora y consumo
    ReDim Intermedio(1 To UBound(Origen), 1 To 3)


    'para las dos variables declaradas debajo necesitas activar la librerí Microsoft Scripting Runtime en herramientas-->Referencias
    Dim Maximo As New Scripting.Dictionary, Minimo As New Scripting.Dictionary, Consumo As New Scripting.Dictionary

    'con un bucle rellenamos el array intermedio separando la fecha de la hora
    For i = 1 To UBound(Origen)
        Fecha = Format(Origen(i, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        Hora = Format(Origen(i, 1), "hh:mm")
        Intermedio(i, 1) = Fecha
        Intermedio(i, 2) = Hora
        Intermedio(i, 3) = Origen(i, 2) 'consumo
        Consumo.Add Fecha + Hora, Origen(i, 2)
    Next i

    'realizamos un bucle para encontrar los valores mínimos y máximos de cada día
    For i = 1 To UBound(Intermedio)
        'Con el maximo
        Fecha = Intermedio(i, 1)
        Hora = Intermedio(i, 2)
        If Maximo.Exists(Fecha) Then 'comprobamos si la fecha ya existe en el diccionario
            If Hora > Maximo(Fecha) Then 'comprobamos si la hora es mayor que la almacenada
                Maximo(Fecha) = Hora 'en caso afirmativo, actualizamos con la hora mayor
            End If
        Else 'si no existe, guardamos fecha y hora
            Maximo.Add Fecha, Hora
        End If

        'Con el minimo
        If Minimo.Exists(Fecha) Then 'comprobamos si la fecha ya existe en el diccionario
            If Hora < Minimo(Fecha) Then 'comprobamos si la hora es menor que la almacenada
                Minimo(Fecha) = Hora 'en caso afirmativo, actualizamos con la hora menor
            End If
        Else 'si no existe, guardamos fecha y hora
            Minimo.Add Fecha, Hora
        End If
    Next i

    Dim Resulatdo As Variant, Key As Variant

    ReDim Resulatdo(1 To Maximo.Count + 1, 1 To 4) 'dimensionamos un array para almacenar los datos finales

    'Ponemos encabezados en la matriz
    Resulatdo(1, 1) = "Día"
    Resulatdo(1, 2) = "Valor mínimo"
    Resulatdo(1, 3) = "Valor máximo"
    Resulatdo(1, 4) = "Consumo"

    'Cargamos la fecha y valores máximos
    i = 2 'Reiniciamos la i
    For Each Key In Maximo.Keys
        Resulatdo(i, 1) = Key
        Resulatdo(i, 3) = Consumo(Key + Maximo(Key))
        i = i + 1
    Next Key

    'cargamos los  valores minimos y calculamos la diferencia
    i = 2 'Reiniciamos la i
    For Each Key In Minimo.Keys
        Resulatdo(i, 2) = Consumo(Key + Minimo(Key))
        Resulatdo(i, 4) = Resulatdo(i, 3) - Resulatdo(i, 2)
        i = i + 1
    Next Key

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count) 'añadimos una hoja al final del libro
        With .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Range("A1", .Cells(UBound(Resulatdo), UBound(Resulatdo, 2))).Value = Resulatdo 'Pegamos los resultados
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias @Damian, tu código me ha sido de ayuda para alguna cosilla en la que todavía andaba atascado!

Comment: @antonio05072019 me alegro que te ayudara, piensa que, además, la forma en la que te lo he hecho puede volcarte los datos en segundos, da igual la cantidad de filas que manejes... Al calcularse todo con arrays y diccionarios funciona muchísimo más rápido.

Answer (score -1):

= CONTAR.Si (A3: A10, "=3/1/2010")

Cuenta el número de celdas del rango A3:A10 con valor Igual  que 3/1/2010

Tomada de :[Sitio de Microsoft Office](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/contar-n%C3%BAmeros-o-fechas-en-funci%C3%B3n-de-una-condici%C3%B3n-976d0074-245d-49e6-bf5f-1207983f82ed)

Comment: La pregunta es sobre macros, no sobre funciones de hoja de cálculo. Si vas a proponer algo diferente a lo solicitado por el autor de la pregunta deberías explicar porqué lo propones.